# Extent Reports: Facing error as 'The method attachReporter(ExtentSparkReporter) is undefined for the type ExtentREports

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, extentreports

I am learning how to create Extent Reports from Youtube. I am trying to write the code for the same. But when I am trying to attach sparkeReports to extentreports, I am facing the mentioned error.

Below is my code:

```java
public class ExtentReports {

ExtentSparkReporter sparkReports;
ExtentReports reports;
ExtentTest test;

@Test 
public void startReport()
{
    sparkReports = new ExtentSparkReporter(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/test-output/MyOwnReports.html");
    reports = new ExtentReports();
    reports.attachReporter(sparkReports);
}
}
```

I tried multiple ways but I am not able to find 'attachReporter()' method due to which I am not able to move ahead. Please help me.

I am using Selenium version 4.8.3 and Extent Reports version 5.0.9

Answer (score 1):

The error that you encountered is because of Naming conflicts between the class you created and a built in class ExtentReports(that has a built in method attachReporter().

To fix this, please consider renaming your class to something different, like MyExtentReports or any other unique name. This will ensure that there is no naming conflict between your class and the Extent Reports library class. After renaming your class, the attachReporter method should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below code is helpful for you

```
public class ExtentReportsDemo {

    ExtentReports extent;

    @BeforeTest

    public void config() {

        String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\reports\\index.html";

        ExtentSparkReporter reporter = new ExtentSparkReporter(path);

        reporter.config().setReportName("Web Automation Results");

        reporter.config().setDocumentTitle("Test Results");

        extent = new ExtentReports();

        extent.attachReporter(reporter);

        extent.setSystemInfo("Tester", "Harsh Singh");

    }

    @Test

    public void initialDemo() {

        extent.createTest("Initial Demo");

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",

            "C:\\\\Users\\\\HarshS\\\\Documents\\\\chromedriver_win32\\\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com");

        driver.getTitle();

        extent.flush();

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. This code helped me to solve my problem.